# Can a Katalon test call another Katalon test that uses variables from an excel file?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder, katalon

I have an automation test that creates a n people that are loaded in an excel file. (Create new Person)

Now I'm trying to create a 'New Case Test' that calls 'Create new Person' to get the people and add them into the case.  However at runtime the New Case Test successfully calls the 'Create new Person' but the attribution is not being pulled from the excel file.

If I run the Create new Person solo, it work just fine. It pulls the data from the excel file and loads the people

Here's the 'New Case Test'

```
//Login
WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('Login'), [:], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)

System.out.println("we are logged in");

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Landing/a_Area'))


//Create People
WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('Create new Person'), [:], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Person Profile (PP000)/a_Case Profile'))

System.out.println("people are created");
```

Comment: Nothing in your code shows data being pulled from Excel file...

If I were you, I'd parameterize that `Create new Person` test case, and try this [modular way to do data-driven testing](https://forum.katalon.com/t/a-modular-way-to-do-data-driven-testing/83831)

Answer (score 0):

At this step Call Test Case create new person Pass the value to that variable. something like.

```
String somedatafromexcel // XLSsheet data. or using Apache poi read the data from excel and pass it. 

//Create People
WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('Create new Person'), [ somevariable : somedatafromexcel ], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
```